# C++ Easiest Way to sort and read this file?

Tags: c++, file, sorting, vector

This file seems a bit... awkward to manage. I need to sort the file by the highest score and here is a small sample of the file at hand:

```
reece 0 
john 5
alex 2
```

Just a few bits of the data. Basically I need it sorted in the following arrangement and then wrote back to the original file:

```
john 5
alex 2
reece 0
```

This also needs to be possible with an infinite amount of data (not inf but you understand what I mean). I have tried this:

```
void read() {
    vector<string> arr;
    string a, b;
    ifstream file1;
    file1.open("Scores.txt", ios::out);
    int count = 0;
    while (file1 >> a >> b) {
        string toVec = a + b;
        arr.push_back(toVec);
        count++;
    }
    for (int outLoop = 0; outLoop < count; outLoop++) cout << arr[outLoop];
}
```

Now this reads from the file and put them into a vector but I don't know what to do from that point. The cout just shows this:

```
reece0john5alex2
```

How would I go about splitting that up and sorting it?

Comment: The easiest way to sort the file is to use an operating system or command line command.

Comment: I don't know any. Thats why I came here... for help...

Comment: Some text editors have sorting capability, you can use them.  Some wordprocessors also have sorting by paragraphs.  Just don't let the WP throw in strange characters.

Comment: Okay but you're expected to try things and do some research.

Comment: You could also open the file in a spreadsheet application, then sort it there.

Answer (score 3):

#### The easiest way

Read the data into a multimap of score (int) to name (string):

```
std::multimap<int, string> data;

{
   std::ifstream fin("Scores.txt");

   std::string name;
   int score;
   while (fin >> name >> score)
      data.insert(std::make_pair(score, name));
}
```

The container named `data` now holds all of your data, indexed (and inherently ascendingly-sorted) by score, with multiple names per score.

Now iterate the multimap backwards using `.rbegin()` and `.rend()` (backwards to get *descendingly*-sorted score), and, for each element, write out the name and the score:

```
{
   std::ofstream fout("Scores.txt");

   for (auto it = data.rbegin(), end = data.rend(); it != end; ++it)
      fout << data->second << ' ' << data->first << '\n';
}
```

#### Future work

The parsing would be more robust if you read from the file line-by-line, then parsed each line individually.

You could simplify the data store (though not much) if you knew that no two people could have the same score, by swapping the `std::multimap` for a `std::map`.

Also, if your input really is very large, you may not want to store all the data in memory at any point. This is hard but possible to avoid. You could consider researching this topic if you find that your program takes too much memory.

Finally, if for some reason you need the original order of names within each score value to be maintained (i.e. you need a *stable sort*) then you'll need to put much more thought into this than I have.

#### Disclaimer

I haven't tested the above snippets, so there may be typos in there. Instead of copy/pasting, read and understand then integrate the ideas into your own code.

Comment: Why do you suggest multimap vs. a standard map?  A standard map also performs sorting.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Because presumably there may be more than one "person" with any given score. I would fall back to a nice `std::map` if I were told that this is not the case.

Comment: The comparator would need to be changed to invert the sort order though, right? It looks like the OP has the scores in descending order.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: No; note `.rbegin()` and `.rend()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair point, I see that in your edit now too.

Comment: I dont have a multimap? Using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @ReeceWard Yes you do. It's in the normal `<map>` include.

Comment: @ReeceWard: You do. Google `std::multimap` to find documentation that you can study. e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap There should also be a section about it in your C++ book?

Comment: for data I get an error of "expression must have pointer type"

Comment: I am trying to get yours too work so I can go through line by line on a working solution

Comment: @ReeceWard: _"for data I get an error of 'expression must have pointer type'"_ Don't know how you managed to get that error, sorry. Perhaps try posting a [mcve] on http://ideone.com or similar.